# How do I save settings using NSUserdefaults

Tags: ios, storage, nsuserdefaults

I am making a tip calculator and the requirement is to have a settings page to go along with the calculator. In the calculator there are three options implemented by a segmented control when each is selected, the value of the tip and the value of the total change. In my settings tab I would like to be able to have the user save their default tip percentage. I know I need to use NSUserdefaults, however I do not know how to do this using two different pages (or one page for that matter). If what I want to achieve is unclear, please let me know I tried my best explaining it thoroughly.

Here is the code for the view controller:

```
@IBAction func onEditingChanged(sender: AnyObject) {

    var tipPercentages = [0.18, 0.2, 0.22]

    let tipPercentage = tipPercentages[tipControl.selectedSegmentIndex]

    let billAmount = billField.text!._bridgeToObjectiveC().doubleValue

    let billAmt = billAmount

    let tip = billAmt * tipPercentage

    let total = billAmt + tip

    tipLabel.text = String(format:"$%.2f", tip)

    totalLabel.text = String(format:"$%.2f", total)

}
```

Here is what I have for the settingsViewController:

```
import UIKit

class SettingsViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var defaultTipControl: UISegmentedControl!



@IBAction func actDefaultTipCont(sender: AnyObject) {

    var tipPercentages = [0.18, 0.2, 0.22]

    var tipPercentage = [defaultTipControl.selectedSegmentIndex]

    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    defaults.setObject(tipPercentage, forKey: "tippingDefault")

    defaults.setInteger(123, forKey: "tippingInteger")

    defaults.synchronize()

}
```

I have just been messing around with the settingsViewController trying to get it to work, it will likely all have to be redone. Here are pictures of the views of the two different pages:

[Entry View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHgHi.png)

[Settings Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bMpA.png)

Thank you ahead of time for the help!

Answer (score 0):

To save then retrieve the data, you want to do something like this:

```
let valueToSave = tipAmount;
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject(valueToSave, forKey: "tipAmount")
```

Then to retrieve it and use it on your main control (for example) do this:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
tipAmount = defaults.objectForKey("tipAmount")
```

the valueForKey method returns whatever you saved in that key previously

NSUserdefaults is basically just a dictionary that will persist over different launches, so just check if you have saved a value for a specific key to access it

Comment: Actually valueForKey is a KVO method. You want objectForKey, or one of the helper methods like doubleForKey

Comment: Should I set valueToSave equal to my tipPercentage that was defined in my settingsViewController? And when I want to retrieve it, where in my main control should I put it? In the viewDidLoad() method?

Comment: yes, so you the tipPercentage will be equal to defaults.objectForKey(""). You can choose whatever key you want to save it under, and as long as you retrieve it with that key, the value will be there. I would save this value whenever they set it, and load it during viewdidload, or whenever they need to see or use it

Comment: Great, thank you I will try to implement this. I'll comment back here if I have more trouble. Thanks for the help!